# Why Collections.max() method is not support Set<Entry<String,Integer>>

Tags: java, collections

```
String key = Collections.max(countMap.entrySet(), (entry1, entry2) -> entry1.getValue() - entry2.getValue()).getKey();
System.out.println(key);
Set<Entry<String,Integer>> entrySet = countMap.entrySet();
Collections.max(countMap.entrySet());
```

Here the first line of code "`Collections.max(Collection<?extends T>, Comparator<? super T>)`" taking two arguments as Set and comparator, which works fine.

But last line code "`Collections.max(countMap.entrySet());`" gives compile time error saying "**The method max(Collection) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (Set>)**".
Need an explanation for above mention code.

Comment: provide `countMap`

Comment: Which entry of these two is bigger? 1: `"abc" -> 1000`; 2: `"CBA" -> 0`. Do you know? Java does not. The [`Collections.max`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max-java.util.Collection-) method takes a Collection of `Comparable`. The elements in the collection need to be `Comparable`, or you need to provide a `Comparator` that would define how to compare elements.

Answer (score 5):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection) has

```
public static <T extends Object & Comparable<? super T>> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll)
```

> All elements in the collection must implement the Comparable interface.

`Entry` doesn't implement the Comparable interface, so you can't pass it to this method.

The `extends` ... `Comparable` in the constraint on the `T` type parameter is what tells the compiler about the requirement.